# How to access the values of an Aria Combobox w/ Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, combobox, wai-aria

I have the following HTML I can't change (part of a corporate tool I have no influence on). This is a dropdown menu and I want to access all values (links) in the dropdown with Javascript/JQuery in a Tampermonkey script:

```
<div class="ant-select-selection ant-select-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-controls="e80ef4e8-f947-4351-88b3-136bb5f3d62f" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0">

<div class="ant-select-selection__rendered"><div class="ant-select-selection-selected-value" title="6 - Live" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">6 - Live</div></div>

<div class="ant-select-selection-selected-value" title="6 - Live" style="display: block; opacity: 1;">6 - Live</div>
</div>
```

**Ultimate goal:** Add a button that opens 5 links from the dropdown by just one click

**What I tried:**

document.getElementsByClassName("ant-select-selection"): returns "undefined"
document.querySelector("combobox"): returns "undefined"

**My understanding**

I know that when I click on the dropdown, the value of

```
aria-expanded="false"
```

changes to "true" and new classes

```
ant-select-open, ant-select-focussed, ant-select-enabled
```

are being  to the element. Adding an evenListener to the click on the dropdown and trying to access the values after the click also did not work (returns only the selected value of the dropdown, not all)

But I don't know how to make use of this to access all the dropdown values.

**In short, my question:** How to access the values of a aria combobox dropdown element?

Answer (score 0):

I copied that html and did:

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ant-select-selection");
x[0].innerHTML = "hello"
```

And it does get the reference to the main `div`.

Is that HTML dynamic? Probably you are trying to access it before it gets rendered, or probably that content is inside an `iframe` element.

Comment: I *think* it is dynamic HTML. What I would expect here is a an HTML Collection to be returned when accessing the element by Class name but as described above, that does not work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Wrap it inside a setTimeout(function(){}, someTime)

Comment: Tried the setTimeout as well, still the result is "undefined"

Comment: Nothing is inside an iframe?